# Centralized Credentials Service For Various Apps

Tags: .net, security, .net-3.5, credentials

We are researching the possibility to build a centralized credentials storage for internal applications. These apps (vb6, vb.net, web apps in asp.net, etc) are using various instances of SQL servers and iSeries. We want to implement a central credentials facility that would act as a security broker. Basically it should work like this:

Client app supplies AppID (I am Sales Application) and EnvironmentID (I am running in QA environment) and in return will get either a connection object (preferred) or encrypted connection string that will allow said application to connect to resources it needs. There will be cases when application needs to connect to two (or more) database resources (i.e. to SQL and iSeries).

What are looking at DP API at the moment, but I am not convinced that DP API is the solution as it tied in with machine key. In our case using machine key isn't feasible, so I want to know if there are other approaches available.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be able to use Windows Impersonation to use the client Kerberos ticket to authenticate and do things on behalf of the client.

The second example on this page explains how to do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302385.aspx